# how to access variables within the Objects

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an object with multiple functions.. i.e.:

```
var test = {

   setA: function(){
     console.log(a)
   }

   endB: function(){
     console.log(a)
   }

}
```

How do I declare variable a so that it can only be accessed in the test object and every function within that the object? and is there anything unique about accessing it than other variables?

I know I can declare a global variable but would rather avoid doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var test = (function() {
    var a = 'test';
    return {

        setA: function(){ console.log(a) },  // <-- was missing a comma

        endB: function(){ console.log(a) }

    };
})();
```

This places `a` in a function invocation which creates a new variable environment. Only function inside this environment will be able to access it.

Your object that contains the functions is returned from the function, and assigned to `test`. Those two functions will continue to have access to `a`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/yWdFw/

This pattern:

```
(function() {

   // your code

})();
```

...is commonly called an immediately invoked function expression or IIFE. You're defining a function, and invoking it immediately. As such, its return value is what's being assigned to `test`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to patrick's answer is adding an attribute to the object and then accessing it via `this`

```
var test = {
   a: 'blah',

   setA: function(){
     console.log(this.a)
   },

   endB: function(){
     console.log(this.a)
   }

}
```